# text-overflow: ellipsis not working in chrome 61.0.3163.100

Tags: css, google-chrome

It dose not work after updating.

CSS:

```
.outer {
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner { display: inline-block }
```

//added semicolon

```
<span class="outer">
    01
    <span class="inner">|</span>
    The first step.
</span>
```

This is actual code.

Comment: make your code available online

Comment: this is working not an issue.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Actual code has a semicolon in place.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.my-elm {
  display:block;    
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-elm">This is demo text.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check its working. You missing semicolon after `display:block`

```css
div{

    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    }
```

```html
<div>afewfafwfawfawfawfawfawfawfawfawefawfawfawfawfawfawfwafawfawfawfwafawfwaf</div>
```